# LongListSelector no Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone, xaml

Eu gostaria de fazer uma tela com um `LongListSelector` desta maneira, pegando resultados de um webservice meu e montando nesse estilo.

Como eu poderia desenvolver isto? Eu sou leigo nesta parte de XAML, é possível indicar os passos básicos para se construir uma interface como a da figura abaixo?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aqui um link demonstrando como migrar o LongListSelector do Windows Phone 8 para o Windows Phone 8.1, ele serve para vocês pois mostra como funciona na versão 8.0.

http://www.visuallylocated.com/post/2014/04/28/Migrating-from-the-LongListSelector-to-the-ListView-in-Windows-Phone-XAML-Apps.aspx

Já na parte de passar parâmetros de uma página para a outra, você faz o seguinte: Você adiciona o evento `SelectionChanged` dentro da `ListBox` populada com os contatos. Então na página que você quer mostrar os detalhes, faça o seguinte: (no exemplo nomeei de `DetalhesContato.xaml`)

Primeiro é preciso criar uma propriedade do tipo da classe que você está usando para os contatos, no exemplo eu utilizo `Contato`, deixe-a como global.

```
//Tanto na MainPage.xaml.cs quanto na DetalhesContato.xaml.cs 
//crie a propriedade
public Contato contato { get; set; }
```

Então no método `OnNavigatedTo` você preenche os componentes da tela

```
//DetalhesContato.xaml.cs    
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    textBlockNome.Text = contato.Nome;
    textBlockTelefone.Text = contato.Telefone;
    //etc
}
```

Já na `MainPage.xaml.cs` você trata o evento `SelectionChanged`

```
//Mainpage.xaml.cs    
private void OnSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Contato c = (sender as ListBox).SelectedItem as Contato;
    //Salva o contato na propriedade da classe, para ser enviado
    this.contato = c;
    this.NavigationService.Navigate(
    new Uri("/DetalhesContato.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
}
```

Para passar o objeto contato para a próxima página, utilize o método `OnNavigatedFrom`

```
//Mainpage.xaml.cs    
protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    //Recupera a próxima página
    DetalhesContato page = e.Content as DetalhesContato
    //é preciso que seja o mesmo nome da propriedade que vc criou no DetalhesContato.xaml.cs
    page.contato = this.contato;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Muito simples!

1. Crie uma classe `Pessoa`, que possua todos os atributos do layout (i.e. Nome, E-mail, Telefones, etc, etc);
2. Crei um `ListBox` no seu arquivo XAML;
3. Referencie um `Binding` para sua classe Pessoa;
4. No .cs, faça com que o seu `ListBox` carregue um `List` de `Pessoa` utilizando o método `meuListBox.itemSource = minhasPessoas`;

Comment: até aí eu já sabia Felipe! O meu problema é que terá que ser um LongListSelector e, ao clicar no "bloco" irá passar para a próxima tela com mais dados da "pessoa".

Comment: Mas muito obrigado pelo começo! Já é de grande ajuda!

Comment: Certo, mas qual é a diferença então? O evento de click você pode utilizar o onHold por exemplo. Dá uma olhada aqui: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.controls.longlistselector(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: Mas eu conseguiria fazer desta maneira de que maneira? Sabe me indicar algum passo-a-passo? Em outras palavras, deixar praticamente igual o layout.

Comment: up para tentar resolver